# Google Analytics for Intranet

Tags: google-analytics

I am unable to load either of the sites from within :
http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js

I only see this : [image: Screen shot of what displays when I try to load the url listed above]

I am not too sure if the loading is appropriate but when I go back and check my google analytics account the activity of my intranet page is not captured. Also, I did add the Tracking code to my "End of Header" section on my Intranet page which is built on Confluence.

Can someone help by directing to some follow through steps I can take to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your Real Time reports to see if the tracking code is working?

If you check the HTML source of your website, do you see the Google Analytics Javascript tracking code?

Follow the instructions here too: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008083?hl=en

Hope it helps!

Comment: I finally got it working by adding the code snippet provided by confluence to support google analytics to confluence.